# How to change Display Template Page url for Blog post in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, friendly-url, liferay-7

I'm using the **Blogs** portlet (Liferay 7.2 GA1) to list all blog posts in a page *example.com/web/guest/blog* and I use the [**Display Template Page**](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/user/-/knowledge_base/u/display-page-example) for blog details.

The problem is that when I open a post the URL changes to:
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/b/blog-post-example

The friendly url for Blog is changed from:
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/blog/
to
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/b/

Is there a way to avoid changing the url?

Comment: have you checked the friendly url settings of your blogs page? You can find this under build > pages > YourBlogPage (3 dots) > Configure
You can define the friendly url there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the friendly url for blogs you should create a new InfoDisplayContributor, you can copy BlogsEntryInfoDisplayContributor.java file and then change the

`public String getInfoURLSeparator()`

Currently, it returns '/b/'.